# Using "onclick" with variable "id" and getElementById (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function displayDate() {
      document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = Date();
    }
```

```html
    <h3 onclick="displayDate()" id="date">Display Date</h3>
    <h3 onclick="displayDate()" id="date">Display Date</h3>
    <h3 onclick="displayDate()" id="date">Display Date</h3>
    <h3 onclick="displayDate()" id="date">Display Date</h3>
    <h3 onclick="displayDate()" id="date">Display Date</h3>
    <h3 onclick="displayDate()" id="date">Display Date</h3>
    <h3 onclick="displayDate()" id="date">Display Date</h3>
    <h3 onclick="displayDate()" id="date">Display Date</h3>
```

Here in this example when I click on any "Display Date" it shows the result in the first one in the column not in the one I clicked .. How can I get the result from everyone I click ?

Comment: The people down there already give you a solution, but you should strictly use an id only one time on a element, when you wanna declare more elements in a group, use classes. An ID is something you can identify as 1 item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This happens because you have set the same id `date` on all `h3` tag items. So when getting the element by id `document.getElementById('date')`, the first element is selected.
- You can get the selected element from event on the function and using that, you can set the value you want as follows.

```js
function displayDate(event) {
  event.target.innerHTML = Date();
}
```

```html
<h3 onclick="displayDate(event)" id="date">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(event)" id="date">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(event)" id="date">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(event)" id="date">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(event)" id="date">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(event)" id="date">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(event)" id="date">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(event)" id="date">Display Date</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

`IDs` Are unique in HTML so don't duplicate them. But for your result you can just give `this` as anargument to your function.

`this` will contain the element you clicked on

Example:

```js
function displayDate(elm) {
  elm.innerHTML = Date();
}
```

```html
<h3 onclick="displayDate(this)">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(this)">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(this)">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(this)">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(this)">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(this)">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(this)">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(this)">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(this)">Display Date</h3>
<h3 onclick="displayDate(this)">Display Date</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you do it like this it's way cleaner an give you a much more flexibility cause having a listener give you the advantage to not right the functions in the html attribute and you can try to add a parent div to your h3 tags and like that you can even remove the class if you don't use them for style and you can make the listener works only on the parent div so you can get rid of the if statment

```js
function displayDate(target) {
     target.innerHTML = Date();
    }

document.addEventListener("click" , (event) => {
if(event.target.className === "date"){
displayDate(event.target)
}

})
```

```html
<h3  class="date">Display Date</h3>
    <h3  class="date">Display Date</h3>
    <h3  class="date">Display Date</h3>
    <h3  class="date">Display Date</h3>
    <h3  class="date">Display Date</h3>
    <h3  class="date">Display Date</h3>
    <h3 class="date">Display Date</h3>
    <h3  class="date">Display Date</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById has nothing to do with the event you are asking the document to return the element with the id date and as it assumes id's to be unique it stops after locating the first match

you need to ask the event which element triggered it this is done via the event args

```
function displayDate(args) {
}
```

then in the args the target is the element that raised the event
so

```
args.target
```

is what you want